# Is there a way to read/write multiple structures or lines using Flatbuffers?

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, flatbuffers

I am using Flatbuffers as a way to store data and the meta-tags with the data. I am using Python and in order to simulate dictionaries, I have two table structures: One for dictionary entries and one to hold a vector of entries. Here is an example of the schema:

```
// Define dictionary structure

table tokenEntry{
  key:string;
  value:int;
}

table TokenDict{
  Entries:[tokenEntry];
}

root_type TokenDict;
```

I wish to write two dictionaries to a single file using Flatbuffers. I want to also read the dictionaries one at a time from the file, and not load both into memory at the same time. I am able to write both to file, one at a time. However, when I read from the file, I get both of the structures at once. The buffer holds all the data from the file. This is not what I want, because later I will have a much larger amount of data in the files. Is there a way to read in just one at a time?

As an example, if I were to use pickle structures, I can write multiple pickles to a file and read them back one at a time. i wish to do the same with Flatbuffers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to write a file as a sequence of individual FlatBuffers, each prefixed with a size. You can do that in Python using `FinishSizePrefixed` (see `builder.py`).

Comment: This helped a lot. Thank you. Is there documentation specifically for working with size prefixed buffers? I believe I have it writing a sequence of individual flatbuffers. Now I am trying to read them back from file. I can get the size of the current flatbuffer being read with util.GetSizePrefixed(buf, offset). Is there an easy way to use that size to grab the data similar to GetRootAsMonster()?

Comment: @webneko yeah, it looks like there is no easy function for that.. the easy answer is to pass an offset of `4` to the usual `GetRoot` function, as the normal buffer starts directly after the size. Would be good if there was a function for it, though.. feel free to file a issue or better yet, PR, on github